# ReactJS - Hosting in subfolder wrong links Switch Route

Tags: reactjs, routes, switch-statement, hosting, router

I'm trying to host my ReactJS project in a subfolder on my webhost.

I put my project (production) in a folder called "dashboard". So now I can access the website by http://hostname/dashboard.

However, when I press on a link on the website, for example "Login", it still goes to http://hostname/login rather than http://hostname/dashboard/login.

What can I do to fix it?

```
function MainContent() {
  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you're using react-router use `basename` https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Comment: @Dominik I'm using <Switch> though, and basename doesn't work for Switch. Should I change it?

Comment: Yes you should :) But note that `basename` is supported in `<BrowserRouter>` `<HashRouter>` and `<StaticRouter>`

Comment: otherwise you can make it a variable `<Route path={\`${yourbasename}/login\`} component={Login} />`

Comment: @Dominik Thanks, if I were to change <Switch> to Router, which Router do you suggest I use?

Comment: I haven't look into that at all. Sorry.

Comment: @Dominik Hey I'm trying to make it work but it seems like when I use BrowserRouter for example, with basename="/dashboard", it's still going to /Login in the main folder..

Comment: Maybe this helps... sorry I don't have time to help directly right now: https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1